# Server Tag Is Not Well Formed when adding html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am getting an error when trying to run a section of jQuery code to be accessed on the serverside. The error is on the var html

The Error is:

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

```
 $("#add_group").click(function (e) {
                var html = '<input id=\"newGroup\" placeholder=\"Group Name\" runat=\"server\" ><button id=\"Save_Group\" type=\"button\" runat=\"server\" onserverclick=\"saveGroupClick_Handler\" >Save</button><ul class=\"sortable\"></ul>';
                $(html).insertBefore($(".sortable:first"));

            });
```

anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *not* create server tag with javascript. You can make tag on server side using asp.net, hide it with `javascript/jQuery` or setting its `Style` to `display:none` on server and access it on both client and server side.

*Asp.net server control*

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server" style="display:none" ></asp:TextBox>
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

*Javascript*

```
$("#add_group").click(function (e) {
    var textbox1 = $('#<%= textbox1.ClientID %>');
    textbox1.insertBefore($(".sortable:first"));
    textbox1.show();
});
```